# Problems with BOOST library c++

Tags: c++, boost, libraries

I want to use the boost library in a c++ project I'm doing in emacs on linux, but I am having troubles getting it to work.  I don't want to actually install it on my machine.  I want to be able to use the regex part of boost.  I want to be able to tar my source files and send them to another computer (that is likely not to have boost installed, nor will I be able to install it) and be able to compile my project.  I have tried using the make file in the regex folder and made both a .a and .so, but I can't get it to compile when linking the library and setting the includes to the boost folder (I have tried multiple folders in the boost directory as well--many of them recommended by Google, but to no avail).  I keep getting a "cannot find regex/config.hpp" error.

Is there anyway to include everything in one file like a .so or .a and get it to work this way?  I am okay with including the regex folder itself as well, butt...

If I were to do it this way would I have to include the whole boost folder with my project anyway?  That might be doable, but I don't want my tar file to be that big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just listing boost as a dependencies and let user install it ?
If not, use Boost bcp to extract regex and its dependencies to a standalone library.

Comment: I can't have the user install it.  I will google Boost bcp and see what comes up.  That is what I want, btw: a standalone library.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to [build regex library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/install.html) in boost. Without this library you can't use 
boost.regex.

Comment: I explained above how I tried this, but couldn't get it to work.